# Reset scroll inside modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog, react-hooks

I'm facing a huge problem. I have a modal that renders a list of texts. The div where the text is shown has a scrollbar, but when I change the text the scrollbar remains at the same spot. If I scroll to the middle and change the text it will appear from the middle and not from the top as it should. 
I've tried this code: window.scrollTo(0,0) but it resets the main page scroll not the modal one.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: share code please

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm understanding your question. It is more helpful if you post the bit of code that's giving you trouble so we can clearly see what's going wrong. That said, window.scrollTo(0,0) will scroll the whole page. If you want to scroll to the top of an element like that, call .scrollTop from the element you wish to scroll. I think you are looking for something like this:

```
$("#myScrollDiv").scrollTop(0);
```